# resolve this issue 'robot' is not recognized in jenkins build execute windows batch command

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I am new to jenkins. I have installed jenkins on windows. i have written test case robot framework. I tried to run robot file test case in jenkins. So i have installed **Robot Framework Plugin** in jenkins. I have added the below command in Execute Windows Batch Command under Build.

```
cd c:\Documents\project
robot fb.robot
```

When i tried to build in jenkins, am getting the  **'robot' is not recognized** error in jenkins console output. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Print your PATH from jenkins and check if the python scripts folder is there, or more like locate the robot executable make sure its location is added to PATH.

Comment: You have to install robot framework on the Jenkins machine (not just the Jenkins plugin). Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your Robot Framework test cases using Jenkins, then you need to know your Jenkins setup. Often a simple setup will execute the jobs on the same machine it's running Jenkins as well. A more advanced setup will likely execute the jobs on separate machines using Jenkins Agents. If that is the case then Python, Robot Framework, your custom modules and your test scripts need to be present on that execution machine.

Answer (score 0):

It was a solution very easy to me. You must go to services.msc in your windows system. Then you must locate jenkins service. Stop Service. After go to login tab and select this account. You must introduce the account you are using (my account is administrator ) and the password if you have. Accept it and now start service.